# Change word to correct word

Tags: prolog

I have seen different examples of change word and after doing it correct word. Specific, I have those

```
word([computer]). 
word([network]).
word([student]).
```

so it will be like this.

```
?-change(o,m,p,c,r,u,t,e],X).
X=[computer]
?-change([t,u,s,t,d,e,n]).
X=[s,t,u,d,e,n,t]
```

Another issue,

```
?-correct[p,r,o,g,r,a,m,m,i,t],X). %delete t
X=[p,r,o,g,r,m,m,i,n,g] %replacing t with g
```

What I want to say is, it is to confusing at me I can't get it in my mind. Is something I can do more easily to get the word I want to be? Because every example has different question about it and all replace letters. Is something "standard" that it could be used and it is easier?

Comment: Any reason for the argument of the `word/1` predicate to be a list?

Comment: I would think you'd want your facts to be simply, `word(computer)`, `word(network)`, etc. There's no need to have them as single element lists such as `[computer]`. In fact, it's just a little extra work to deal with it. But once you have an *atom* such as `computer`, you can use `atom_chars` to get the list of character codes.

Comment: could you do me an example ,because i didn't catch it.Prolog is difficult language :/

Comment: Do a little experimenting. At the Prolog prompt, enter `atom_chars(computer, L).` and see what you get. Go to the Prolog documentation and explore the other predicates there that manipulate lists and atoms.

Comment: The exact same question was asked again here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897337/how-change-word-different-cases/50909427#50909427