# How to change incorrect spelling for the correct word?

Tags: prolog

How do I correctly change the spelling of the words:

Example Use 1:

```
?-correct([p,c,o,m,t,e,r,u],X)
X=[c,o,m,p,u,t,e,r]
```

Example Use 2 :

```
?-change([u,s,t,e,n,,t,d],X)
Y=[ s,t,u,d,e,n,t]
```

How will it work? This is what I did for the first example:

```
x([c,o,m,p,u,t,e,r]).
y([s,t,u,d,e,n,t]).

correct(Word, CorrectWord) :-
    select(_, Word, CorrectWord),
    x(CorrectWord).
```

Comment: X(CorrectWord).` is a syntax error in Prolog. You cannot have a functor that begins with a capital letter. `X=([c,o,m,p,u,t,e,r)]` (also includes a typographical error) and `Y=[(s,t,u,d,e,n,t)]` also do not make sense in this context. They are unterminated terms and a syntax error.

Comment: yes i see ,i tryed but i failed . I just wanted  to do have c,m,p,u,t,e,r and i want to change it to this compouter

Comment: You really should learn basic, proper Prolog syntax before attempting a bugger problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a knowledge base of words:

```
word([c,o,m,p,u,t,e,r]).
word([s,t,u,d,e,n,t]).
```

Now we need to think about the problem you wish to solve, you want to know if `Word` and `CorrectWord` both contain exactly the same letters but in a different order. So I suggest making the order the same before comparing them:

```
correct(Word, CorrectWord) :-
    word(CorrectWord),  % Search through the knowledge base of words
    sort(Word, S), sort(CorrectWord, S).  % Compare the two words
```

sort/2 is a built-in for SWI-Prolog, the comparison is done by asking for `S` to unify to the same thing, which is the sorted words. The disadvantage of this method is that it won't run backwards, but you also don't need correct\2 and change\2. It also allows you to ask questions like this:

```
?- correct([p, c, o, m, t, e, r, u], [c|T]).
T = [o, m, p, u, t, e, r].
```

For the new example case, `[o,o,n,p,u,t,e,r]` and to handle the odd extra letter, you can use a measure of similarity like the Jaccard Coefficient. `intersection/3`, `length/2`, `append/3` are all built-in to SWI-Prolog. I'm using `append/3` as union.

```
jaccard_coef(L1, L2, JC) :-
    intersection(L1, L2, I),
    length(I, LI),
    append(L1, L2, U),
    length(U, LU), 
    JC is LI/LU.
```

Now your correct clause becomes:

```
correct(Word, CorrectWord) :-
    word(CorrectWord),  % Search through the knowledge base of words
    sort(Word, S), sort(CorrectWord, S).  % Compare the two words
correct(Word, CorrectWord) :-.
    word(CorrectWord),
    jaccard_coef(Word, CorrectWord, JC),
    JC > 0.4. % Where 0.4 is a number chosen as a threshold.
```

`0.4` is chosen so the example passes. 1 would require an exact match, adjust it for how strict you require it to be, or you could update the method to find the maximum jaccard_coef to return only the most similar word rather than a selection of similar words.

Comment: i am not sure that you understand what i said.Let's say i have the word  computer.This is the right word,if lets say there are issues like this c,o,m,m,p,u,t,e,r or issues with  o,o,n,p,u,t,e,r or any case it can be that makes the word isn't as it should be,i want to to compare as you did and will give me the right word back

Comment: it may for example word or correct word has more letters.I want to  do the wrong word ,o,m,p,u,r,e,r what ever in computer

Comment: That is a much bigger problem than you stated in the question. You will need several clauses to the `correct/2` predicate to accomplish this. In the new example, `[o,o,n,p,u,t,e,r]` you'd need to find the closest matching correct words, using some measure such as Jaccard Distance. This is non-trivial.

Comment: I dont know if you get what i mean,i want in any case to take the result fix a word like o,o,n,p,u,t,e,r  or what ever to this computer ,this is difficult?more advance?what?

Comment: More complex, I've updated the answer to include a solution.